# Hyper-V-Manager does not show any VMs and the "actions" pane is empty

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I created a VM using Hyper-V-Manager and was able to start the VM and use it for a week.
Today Hyper-V-Manager would not show me my VM.

I checked `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Virtual Machines` and was able to find some files and an empty folder:

- 16B1743A-42BA-4A83-BEFC-847456184561\
- 16B1743A-42BA-4A83-BEFC-847456184561.vmcx
- 16B1743A-42BA-4A83-BEFC-847456184561.vmgs
- 16B1743A-42BA-4A83-BEFC-847456184561.VMRS

The date & time of these files match the time i turned off the machine yesterday.
My virtual HDD (the .vhdx file) also exists in its custom place.

The Hyper-V-Manager does not show any options in the 'actions' pane on the right side (stuff like: New, Import Virtual Machine..., Hyper-V Settings..., etc.). The only options it shows is 'Connect to Server...' .

[image]

**Software Version**
Windows 10 Pro
Hyper-V-Manager: Management Console 3.0, Version 1803

Comment: Cryptic names such as? Can you post a screenshot... you may have some filesystem corruption...

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is looking at this thread, the issue also may be that the "Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management" Service is not running. If it is turned off, you will get the same symptoms.

Comment: Closinng the Hyper-V manager, restarting the "Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management" service and starting the Hyper-V manager again helped in my case, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

1. Click that Connect to Server link. You should get a dialog with a radio button for "local computer" and one for "remote computer". Click the former, then click OK and see what happens. If that doesn't work, try choosing "remote computer" and typing localhost into the address box or similar. (I'm nowhere near my Win10 PC at the moment, which is why I can't give you more specific directions.)
2. Are you running Hyper-V Manager elevated? This is sometimes required for it to be able to connect to the Hyper-V manager service.

Comment: Unfortunately or rather fortunately, I do not have that problem anymore. Since I can not reproduce the problem, I also can not test your solution. 
My Computer did not shut down over the weekend, I used the power button to turn it off. After booting the thing, Hyper-V-Manager showed everything, leaving me clueless about the problem and solution.

Comment: What's crazy is I have precisely the same problem as you, except multiple restarts and also restarting the "Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management" service didn't seem to resolve the problem at all. Very annoying and mysterious; odd too considering Docker is still able to access the VM.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.
Search "Hyper-V Manage", now right-click it and select "Run As Administrator"

[image: run as admin]

Type in your credentials, and then hit enter. Now you should see the VMs' that you created:

[image: VMS]